# Access to path [Destination Address] is denied - when creating a new directory - VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, access-denied

I am trying to upload a file to a newly created directory,
 i manage to create it but can not place the file there because access is denied,
 How can i allow the acces to the directory?

```
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Upload Status"></asp:Label>
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
```

If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
 Try
                Dim file = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
                Dim Extention As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)
                If Extention = ".jpeg" OrElse Extention = ".jpg" Then

`If FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 2097152 Then
                    Label1.Text = "File Too Big"
                Else
                    Dim directoryPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/bussnisses")

                    If Not Directory.Exists(directoryPath) Then
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath)
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(directoryPath)
                    Else
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(directoryPath)
                    End If
                    Label1.Text = "complete"
                End If

            Else
                Label1.Text = "  jpeg or jpg"

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: Have you given the IIS account permission to the directory in question?

Comment: Did you get the error on the Directory.CreateDirectory line or when calling the `SaveAs` method?

Comment: im using locahost and yes IIS has the correct promitions , the break happens when i try to save the file in the newly created directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of you have the error in the CreateDirectory call or afterward. I am sure that the FileUpload control doesn't have a SaveAs method and this is on the PostedFile object and that you need to pass a FileName not a Directory name

```
Dim directoryPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/bussnisses")
If Not Directory.Exists(directoryPath) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath)
End If

Dim destFile = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
destFile = Path.Combine(directoryPath, destFile)
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(destFile)
Label1.Text = "complete"
```